# JSON.parse give me an error but JSONLint say it's a valid json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a graphic with jqplot extracting the values vía mysql ajax, I have read so much information about this, i'm IT and to me it's a little embarrasing making this question. It's causing me a big headache :(

I've spent 20 days resolving this but i can't alone myself, anyone can help me please? I have tried almost everything (json.parse, parsejson, getjson, datatype html, datatype json, method get and post.....)

I know it will be easy...
Why crash when i try to do JSON.parse(resultado) ?

http://jsonlint.com/ say it's a Valid Json, but when I try to do JSON.parse he give me an exception saying ("JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data")

**It seems is the [ character**

Here is the php:

```
<?php include('conex.php');
$datos=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Meteorologia");
$arrDatos = array();
while ($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($datos))
    $arrDatos[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rs);
echo json_encode($arrDatos);
?>
```

I obtain:

```
[{"FECHA":"2015-01-01","OZONO":"3","KT":"2","VV":"4"},{"FECHA":"2016-03-03","OZONO":"68","KT":"86","VV":"78"}]
```

The js is:

```
try
{
    var strHtml = "";
    $.ajax({
            global: false,
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#form").attr('action'),
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(resultado){
                alert('success!!'+resultado);
                console.log(typeof resultado);
                console.log(resultado);
                //var datosRecibidos = JSON.parse(resultado);
                //var datosRecibidos = jQuery.parseJSON(resultado);
                var lista = "";
                $.each( resultado, function( key, value ) {
                        if(value.FECHA == "2015-01-01")
                        {
                            alert('si!!');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('sino!!');
                        }
                });
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('Error!!: '+data);
            }
    });
}
catch(ex)
{
    alert("catch!!"+ex);
}
```

With the $each key value ... can i move inside the array?

Comment: Before your call to `JSON.parse()` add `console.log(typeof resultado)`. I suspect the problem may be that the response has already been parsed.

Comment: OK, if it's saying it's a string, the next thing to do is verify that it's the *correct* string. You should be able to see the ajax HTTP transaction in the browser developer console. With Firebug, if the response is valid JSON, you'll even see a JSON tab.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `value.fecha` should be `value.FECHA`.

Comment: He clearly set data type 'html', but by all means make random guesses guys.

Comment: @Jhawins I can't count how many times posted code turns out not to be the actual code in use, and trying to re-parse already parsed JSON is an extremely common error.

Comment: @Jhawins I didn't answer :)

Comment: @Pointy I don't know why I try sometimes lol

Comment: OP should earn to log actual response data, this is not actual response data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things (changing datatype json,html,..., method get, post...)

I debugging with the address file:///**C:/xampp/htdocs**/traerdatos/index.html

instead of **http://localhost**/traerdatos/index.html

So the solution is to **CHANGE THE ADDRESS TO LOCALHOST**

*(Thanks to reformed that helps me with his vision)*

Novel error =)